# why cant we put a decimal in the for range in python

Tags: python

For example, I put this:

for i in range (2,n**0.5+1,2):

```
      print(i)
```

And it doesn't work. I tried putting 1/2 instead but it didn't work 
I have python 3.6

Comment: Because the function isn't designed to accept non-integer arguments.

Comment: `help(range)` at the console can give you information such as @juanpa.arrivillaga provided

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `range` only accepts integers. But you can use this function instead:

```
def frange(start, stop, step):
    current = start
    while current < stop:
        yield current
        current += step
```

Comment: Note that this is likely to run a step more or less than you intended, due to floating-point inaccuracies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately i haven't learned that function yet, therefore, im not allowed to use it